# How to use plugins_url() inside PHP stylesheet file

Tags: php, css, plugins-url

I created a plugin and use php file as stylesheet file

PHP style sheet file:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8');
    $x_position = 0;
    $y_position = -40px;
?>
.blugin_box{
    width:140px;
    height:140px;
    background:url("/mysite/wp-content/plugins/myimgfolder/my_img.png") no-repeat $x_position $y_position;
}
```

**It works well** , **but** when I try to use plugins_url() as below, **stylesheet stop loading**

```
background:url(plugins_url()."/myimgfolder/my_img.png") no-repeat $x_position $y_position;
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
background:url(<?php echo plugins_url().'/myimgfolder/my_img.png'; ?>) no-repeat <?php echo $x_position.' '.$y_position; ?>;
```

It will allow you to echo the PHP elements into your style.

EDIT:

You also need to close the file, you're trying to mix unwrapped PHP with your CSS. Your PHP variables aren't escaped either. I've tested the code below, and it works fine:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8');
    $x_position = 0;
    $y_position = '-40px';
?>
.blugin_box{
    width:140px;
    height:140px;
    background:url(<?php echo plugins_url().'/myimgfolder/my_img.png'; ?>) no-repeat <?php echo $x_position.' '.$y_position; ?>;
}
```

I suggest using:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

While you're debugging so that you can see any PHP errors on screen, or check your log files :-)

Comment: I tried your advice but it didn't work and file stop loading, as I mentioned in my question file stop loading if I add `plugins_url()`

Comment: Updated the answer, tested and it works. Try enabling errors to your display in PHP to see where your errors are